# How to remove the black line between tablerows

Tags: android, android-tablelayout

I am currently making a connect 4 game and using drawables as resource. I have 7 images per row and when displaying the rows and adding them to the tablerow it adds a black line between them. I have tried every options of scaling and cropping removing margins and paddings but i still have the black line. How do i remove that?

[image]

The xml :

```
<TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/table_jeu"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom">

    </TableLayout>
```

and the programmatically generated rows

```
for (int i = 0; i < nbRangées; i++)
        {
            TableRow.LayoutParams p = new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            TableRow rangée = new TableRow(this);
            rangée.setLayoutParams(p);
            rangée.setWeightSum(nbColonnes);
            table.addView(rangée);

            for (int j = 0; j < nbColonnes; j++)
            {
                final ImageView _case = new ImageView(this);
                _case.setImageResource(R.drawable.case_vide);
                _case.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                p = new LayoutParams();
                p.weight = 1;
                //p.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
                _case.setLayoutParams(p);
                _case.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
                _case.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
                _case.setTag(j);
                //_case.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
                _case.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent arg1) {
                        sonJeton.start();
                        colonne = (int) _case.getTag();
                        partie.joue();

                        return false;
                    }
                });

                rangée.addView(_case);
            }
        }
```

Comment: can you please post your xml code.?

Comment: I have edited the question with the content of the XML and the part in java class!